# Introduce parameter object refactoring in IntelliJ 13

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, intellij-13, parameter-object

I would like to perform an automatic "Introduce parameter object" refactoring in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1. It seems that this refactoring was available in version 10.5, according to [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/introduce-parameter-object.html), but I can't seem to find it in the current version.

In a nutshell, I want IntelliJ to create a class encapsulating a series of parameters of a method, and replace the parameters with an instance of that type.

Is this refactoring really no longer available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the cursor on the method and from the top menu choose `Refactor -> Extract -> Parameter Object`. In the dialog that's opened, choose the class' name, package etc. and press "Refactor".